# How to soften hard gummy candies

Tags: candy

I’ve been eating spearmint gummy candies and spice drop candies.  Most of the time they are the perfect consistency and I’m able to eat them with no problem. I recently purchased a large bag of gummy candies and I can hardly eat them because they are too hard. Can anyone please explain how to soften them and keep them soft? I have a picture of one below.  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a good article that provides 5 methods to soften hard gummy candies and an explanation for this phenomenon. You can find the methods below or at https://www.tophomeapps.com/how-to-soften-gummy-bears/.

As I had the same issue, I tried the water method and it worked great for me! Just got them out a lot earlier, after ca. 5 min. Also, it's important that the water is warm but not too hot, otherwise, they melt.

> **A Bowl of warm water** -
> For softening gummy bears, you need to re-hydrate
> them. Place gummy bears in a bowl of warm water. Don’t use cold water
> as gelatin is soluble in warm water.
> Around 20 minutes they will reach desired consistency. As you keep
> them in water for longer, more water they will absorb. They will grow
> also more and become softer as you keep them for longer.
>
> **Microwave Method** - Take a microwave-safe plate and place a paper towel
> on a plate. Keep gummy bears on a plate arranged in a row.
> Sprinkle gummy bears with warm water. Microwave them on low for 10
> seconds. Check the softness of the gummy candies.
> If they are not getting soften to the desired level, heat them for an
> additional 5 seconds.
> Allow it to cool for 10 minutes. Store it in a plastic bag zipper.
>
> **Keep Gummies with bread** - Take a bag and a piece of bread. Keep the
> piece of bread and gummy bear candies into the bag.
> Clip the bag and make sure it locked properly.
> Place it somewhere in a warm place. It will get soft within a day just
> like fresh.
> You can also soften the hard cookies like this way.
>
> **Spray with warm water** - Spraying with warm water also works to soften
> hard gummy bears. You just need to spray the warm water on gummy
> bears.
> Place the gummy bears on a plate. Spray them with warm water twice.
> Just two or three sprays will work. But spray them till you reach
> desired consistency.
>
> **Keeping in a backpack or pocket** - You can also try a simple trick to
> soften the gummy bears. You can just put it in a pocket or backpack.
> They will get warm and squishy after about 5 minutes. Depends upon the
> hardness and your desired softness, time may be varying.

Comment: I am sorry, Microwaving Gummy Bears just has shades of the 80s movie Gremlins.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately... you can't really soften them without some serious degradation or time.  They are died out, and water diffusion does not easily occur without melting everything down and reforming them, so put them in a warm, humid spot for a week and see how you like the consistency after that.

I've had this happen at the commercial level, and we just throw it out because it's such a strain on resources to recondition them

Comment: Commercial quantity gummies..... hmm...